# TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection failing despite available TFS server

Tags: tfs

So, I have a TFS server at http://mytfsserver:8080. I'm connected to it fine from visual studio doing all the usual TFSy things without any issue at all.

I'm trying to connect from code though - I do the following:

```
tfs =  TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://mytfsserver:8080"));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

But I get a `TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException`.

I'm not connecting to my server in any funny ways, so what is different about what I'm doing to what VS does when it connects?

Comment: The answers below are both correct, it also turned out that I had to add my credentials in manually which might be a gotcha for anyone else having this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the collection name at the end of the Uri

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://TFS:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `/tfs` to your server URI.

```
var tfsServerUri = new Uri("http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs");
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsServerUri);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```